# Grails Webapp failure to deploy to AWS elasticsearch issue

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, weceem

I am using Grails 2.4.4 and Amazon Web Service Free Tier

I used this [tutorial](http://www.inoneo.com/en/blog/5/amazon-aws/deploy-a-grails-application-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk) and was able to deploy a working Grails app to Elastic Beanstalk.

I installed the [Weceem Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/weceem). I am able to get the CMS to run locally, connecting to a local running sql database.

My AWS instance is running : 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.1.0 running Tomcat 7 Java 7 with default RDS MySQL 5.6.22

Below is the AWS log that shows the stacktrace:

```
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:164)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:497)
... 3 more
2015-05-14 21:33:31,750 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:164)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:497)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-05-14 21:33:31,750 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchableClassMappingConfigurator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:164)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:497)
... 3 more
2015-05-14 21:33:31,750 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchableClassMappingConfigurator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:164)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:497)
... 3 more
2015-05-14 21:33:31,750 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:164)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:497)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-05-14 21:33:31,750 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchableClassMappingConfigurator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:164)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:497)
... 3 more
2015-05-14 21:33:31,751 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchableClassMappingConfigurator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:164)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:497)
... 3 more
2015-05-14 21:33:31,751 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:164)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:497)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-05-14 21:33:31,751 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchableClassMappingConfigurator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:164)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:497)
... 3 more
```

Build Config:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
   // test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
         runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"
        compile ':weceem:1.3'

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

DataSource(with user/pass removed)

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    //jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "user"
    password = "pass"
    dialect = org.hibenate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/awscms"
            username = "user"
            password = "pass"
        }
    }

    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/awscms"
            username = "user"
            password = "pass"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            username = "user"
            password = "pass"
            pooled = true
            dbCreate = "update"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://aapshm8qd9vgr5.cwahcflovjur.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/ebdb?user=user&password=pass"
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
            properties {
                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                testOnBorrow = true
                testOnReturn = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1800000
                numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1800000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Weceem [uses the elasticsearch plugin](http://jcatalog.github.io/weceem-plugin/guide/2.ConfigurationAndInstallation.html) so you need to add [some settings](https://github.com/jCatalog/weceem-app/blob/master/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy#L172) in your Grails config file in order to configure a local Elasticsearch node, something similar to this (but matching your environment and your needs)

```
elasticSearch.datastoreImpl = 'hibernateDatastore'
elasticSearch.bulkIndexOnStartup = true
elasticSearch.disableAutoIndex = false
elasticSearch.client.mode = 'local'
elasticSearch.index.store.type = 'memory' // store local node in memory and not on disk
```

Comment: I cannot understand why weceem plugin did not set the default values for elasticsearch as it is described since https://github.com/jCatalog/weceem-app/blob/master/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy#L209